# Determining the interior of $([-1, 1]\times[-1, 1])\setminus \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^2 : d((0, 0), y) < 0.25 \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $M = (\mathbb{R}^2, d_e)$ be the metric space, with $d_e$ the Euclidean metric. Let $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $$C = ([-1, 1]\times[-1, 1]) \setminus \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^2 : d((0, 0), y) < 0.25 \}.$$

How will $\operatorname{Int}(C)$ look like in terms of sets and their unions/products etc.?

My guess is that $\operatorname{Int}(C) = (\;(-1, 1)\times(-1, 1)\;)\setminus \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^2 :  d((0, 0), y) \leq 0.25 \}$. Am I right?

Comment: You are right...